# Replacement of Poco::AutoPtr with boost

Tags: boost, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, poco-libraries

I am trying to replace `Poco::AutoPtr` with some alternative in boost. Here is what I have discovered so far:

What I have: below classess are being used with `Poco::AutoPtr`. They need to implement reference counted method with implementing `duplicate()` and `release()` methods.

I am using above `referece_counted.h` and `Poco::AutoPtr` in a complex class hierarchy with multiple inheritance and c++ diamond problems.

A simplified version of classes would look something like this

```
class A : virtual public ReferenceCounted
{
...
}

class B : public A
{
...
}

class C : public A
{
...
}

class D : public A, B
{
...
}
```

and the list goes on for few more level deep. I know that this needs to be refactored with a simplified hierarchy but I wanna remove `Poco::AutoPtr` first with proper replacement in boost:

What I have found so far:
I have found that [boost::intrusive_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html) is the closest smart pointer that can be a good replacement of `Poco::AutoPtr`.

I am however not able to implement the proper solution with this because the intrusive_ptr requires intrusive_ptr_add_ref and intrusive_ptr_release methods created specifically for each class with which I need to use the pointer. I tried using templates but still not having proper solution at hand.

Also one more issue is that I need to typecast from base to derived class many times.

is intrusive_ptr is the correct smart pointer for this usage ? and if yes.. can anybody give me suggestion regarding how to use the same ?

Comment: No .. I get crazy crashes if I try to change.. so for the time being I copied the poco classes in my code and replaced the atomic counter. It works fine atm. I will have second go at it later.

Answer (score 1):

> I am however not able to implement the proper solution with this
>   because the intrusive_ptr requires intrusive_ptr_add_ref and
>   intrusive_ptr_release methods created specifically for each class with
>   which I need to use the pointer.

No-no. It is should not be hard. As [Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html) says:

> On compilers that support argument-dependent lookup,
>   intrusive_ptr_add_ref and intrusive_ptr_release should be defined in
>   the namespace that corresponds to their parameter; otherwise, **the
>   definitions need to go in namespace boost**.

Try this: main.cpp (built ok with "g++ main.cpp -o main -lboost_system")

```
#include <boost/intrusive_ptr.hpp>  

class MyObject
{
  public:
    void duplicate(){ 
       // ...
    }
    void release(){
       // ...
    }
};

namespace boost {

template <class T>
void intrusive_ptr_add_ref( T * po ) {
    po->duplicate(); // your internal realization
}

template <class T>
void intrusive_ptr_release( T * po ) {
    po->release(); 
}

}        

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // ...
    boost::intrusive_ptr<MyObject> ptr( new MyObject );
    boost::intrusive_ptr<MyObject> ptr2 = ptr; // should work
}
```